# saving a struct for post fetching

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am newbie to C. I have a csv file with a particular structure. I created struct and and read the data from csv file and print it using defined struct. However, instead of printing the struct I need to save it so I an access it for later processing. So far, I have understood I need to use dynamic memory allocation but I am totally lost right now. any leads would be really useful.

The inputfile as follows,

```
2,33.1609992980957,26.59000015258789,8.003999710083008
5,15.85200023651123,13.036999702453613,31.801000595092773
8,10.907999992370605,32.000999450683594,1.8459999561309814
11,28.3700008392334,31.650999069213867,13.107999801635742
14,7.046000003814697,23.5939998626709,6.254000186920166
```

My code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct O_data
{
   unsigned int index;
   float x;
   float y;
   float z;
};

struct O_data * deserialize_data(struct O_data *data, const char *input,   const char *separators)
{
   char *p;
   struct O_data tmp;
   if(sscanf(input, "%d,%f,%f,%f", &data->index, &data->x, &data->y, &data->z) != 7)
   return NULL;
   return data;
}

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   FILE *stream;
   char *line = NULL;
   size_t len = 0;
   ssize_t nread;
   struct O_data somedata;
   if (argc != 2) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   stream = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   if (stream == NULL) {
       perror("fopen");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1) {
       deserialize_data(&somedata, line, ",");
// How do I save some data to memory here to access it later like somedata[i] for ith struct later outside main. 
       printf("index: %d, x: %f, y: %f, z: %f\n", somedata.index, somedata.x, somedata.y, somedata.z);
   }
   free(line);
   fclose(stream);
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> // How do I save some data to memory here to access it later like somedata[i] for ith struct later outside main.

you can use an array of `struct O_data` using *malloc* then *realloc* to allocate then make longer that array having an unknown number of entries until you read all the file

---

Warning in `deserialize_dat`

> ```
> sscanf(input, "%d,%f,%f,%f", &data->index, &data->x, &data->y, &data->z)
> ```

*index* is *unsigned* but you use `%d`, must be `%u`, it is the same in *printf* in *main*

*tmp* and *p* are unused, like the parameter *separators*

---

A proposal can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct O_data
{
   unsigned int index;
   float x;
   float y;
   float z;
};

struct O_data * deserialize_data(struct O_data *data, const char *input)
{
   return (sscanf(input, "%u,%f,%f,%f", &data->index, &data->x, &data->y, &data->z) != 7) 
     ? NULL : data;
}

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   FILE *stream;
   char *line = NULL;
   size_t len = 0;
   ssize_t nread;
   struct O_data * somedata = NULL;
   size_t nelts = 0;

   if (argc != 2) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   stream = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   if (stream == NULL) {
       perror("fopen");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1) {
     if ((somedata = realloc(somedata, (nelts + 1) * sizeof(struct O_data))) == NULL) {
       fprintf(stderr, "error not enough memory");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
     deserialize_data(&somedata[nelts++], line);
   }
   free(line);
   fclose(stream);

   /* print and free */
   for (size_t i = 0; i != nelts; ++i)
     printf("index: %u, x: %f, y: %f, z: %f\n",
            somedata[i].index, somedata[i].x, somedata[i].y, somedata[i].z);

   free(somedata);

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra a.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f
2,33.1609992980957,26.59000015258789,8.003999710083008
5,15.85200023651123,13.036999702453613,31.801000595092773
8,10.907999992370605,32.000999450683594,1.8459999561309814
11,28.3700008392334,31.650999069213867,13.107999801635742
14,7.046000003814697,23.5939998626709,6.254000186920166
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out f
index: 2, x: 33.160999, y: 26.590000, z: 8.004000
index: 5, x: 15.852000, y: 13.037000, z: 31.801001
index: 8, x: 10.908000, y: 32.000999, z: 1.846000
index: 11, x: 28.370001, y: 31.650999, z: 13.108000
index: 14, x: 7.046000, y: 23.594000, z: 6.254000
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out f
==2439== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2439== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2439== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2439== Command: ./a.out f
==2439== 
index: 2, x: 33.160999, y: 26.590000, z: 8.004000
index: 5, x: 15.852000, y: 13.037000, z: 31.801001
index: 8, x: 10.908000, y: 32.000999, z: 1.846000
index: 11, x: 28.370001, y: 31.650999, z: 13.108000
index: 14, x: 7.046000, y: 23.594000, z: 6.254000
==2439== 
==2439== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2439==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2439==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 5,832 bytes allocated
==2439== 
==2439== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2439== 
==2439== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2439== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Note I *realloc* adding only one entry in the array each time, if there are a lot of values in the file it can be better to add several entries rather than just one in the *realloc* when needed

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am trying exactly what you suggested but I need some lead. I am totally lost there.

Comment: @dipaksanap I edited my answer with a proposal and executions. Note I Move the _printf_ after the loop where you read in the file to show the values are memorized

Comment: Hi @bruno , it works well ! Thanks a ton. I just have a small question, you mentioned to add several lines in case of large data. Do I just add (nelts + bignumber). Also, what does ? Null : data ; do ? Thanks.

Comment: @dipaksanap currently I know there is not enough space at each loop because grow one by one, if more you need to differentiate let's say the _allocatedNelts_ and the _usedNelts_ to know when you need to reallocate (they are equal) and yes _realloc_ with _allocatedNelts_ + number_greater_than_1